# android emulator loading in Landscape mode everytime I start emulator any idea?

Tags: android, android-emulator

when I start emulator or run any application then it's stared in Landscape mode.. Like Tablet. App Orientation is Horizontal but not working here. I attached image also with this. Before some days it's working well but after I deleted .android folder from Users in PC then it's behave like this. Any idea how to open emulator in Normal Mode?! You can see image here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ZJdqskEQLWbWJ5NjRKMTJpbVk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> on Mac to change the landscape to portrait and vice versa.
- <kbd>left-ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>on Windows 7.
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>on Linux.
- <kbd>left-ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>on Windows 7 
  It works fine in Windows 7 for android emulator to change the landscape orientation to portrait and vice versa.